# What's difference between Apple developers account

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

If I login with university account and download xcode, installed it. After I got another enterprise account, do I have to login and download again? Besides that, what difference when using those 2 accounts? Thanks.

Comment: no need to install and download again... You can download xcode even when you have just a free developer account

Comment: Is there any place I can see what level is my account? I checked member center, but found nothing. Thanks.